# Conflicting Settings in OSX Server Profile Manager (Groups and Users/Devices)

Tags: osx-server, profile-manager

please help me understand what happens if you have nested groups in Profile Manager and you apply conflicting Settings. Which Setting will be Carried oft?
E.g.:
I have the following groups:

```
All
|-Teachers
|-Students
```

So Teachers and Students are nested in All. 
When you activate a Setting or configure a payload in All. And you deactivate the Setting in Teachers: how will a User belonging to teachers be configured?

And what Happens if you additionally change this users' settings conflicting with the above.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how this is handled?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this question myself accidentially.
Please check [this site](http://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/mac-operating-systems/how-managed-preferences-are-inherited-combined-and-overridden-in-lion-server/) for a more detailed explanation. There is no single answer to this

Condensed:

> Some settings, such as controlling which items are opened at login, are cumulative because no one particular setting overrides another — any number of items can be opened at login.
>   Some settings are inherited from workgroups to the user level or from within nested workgroups. Settings with only one ultimate outcome — such as the position of the Dock onscreen — use an order of priority to override the same setting for different account levels. The prioritization of conflicting preferences to override the same setting also applies for inheritance. The order of inheritance and overriding preferences is

- Workgroup (the least specific level)

  - Device group

    - Device

      - User (the most specific level)

For example, a preference set at the workgroup level can’t override the same preference set for the computer group, computer, or user level. In this sense, a preference set for the user always wins when overriding other levels.